# Mixing constraints and autoresizing masks

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autolayout, xcode6

To be 100% clear, I've never used Auto Layout and constraints (I usually disable it at once) and I'm always using the usual Auto-resizing masks for layouts.

However, in my most recent project, I ended up using [LITabControl](https://github.com/monyschuk/LITabControl) (which *does* use Auto Layout and constraints). So my project is all set up the old-way (with autoresizing masks), with the only exception being `LITabControl`.

But, this is where the trouble starts.

First, I've been experiencing all sorts of weird resizing issues (that would normally work).

Last but not least, I keep getting from time to time errors in the log window along these lines:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints: (
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6080000897e0 h=--& v=--& H:[NSView:0x600000123480(116)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000008d6b0 H:|-(0)-[NSView:0x600000123480](LTR)   (Names: '|':NSSplitView:0x6000001223a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000008d7f0 H:[NSView:0x600000123480]-(1)-[NSView:0x6000001230c0](LTR)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000089ce0 h=--& v=--& H:|-(116)-[NSView:0x6000001230c0]   (Names: '|':NSSplitView:0x6000001223a0 )>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000008d7f0 H:[NSView:0x600000123480]-(1)-[NSView:0x6000001230c0](LTR)>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
```

Which still looks pretty... cryptic to me.

I've tried using `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` (and setting it to `NO` for my main views, and subviews) - pretty randomly I must admit (I mean I simply do *not* know what I'm doing!) - but this led to even worst issues, with views disappearing completely.

What is going on here? How should I approach that?

I *know* that `LITabControl` (my only AutoLayout element) is the cause, but I still need it. Any chance of somehow "converting" it to using Autoresizing masks? What should I do?

Comment: What happens if you enable autolayout for your project and change, `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES` (i.e. The opposite of what you have done). I think this will convert you autoresizing mask into constraints allowing your other views to work with the tab control. Side note, autolayout has a learning curve, but is incredible powerful and cool!

Comment: Use autolayout, set 'setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints' To YES for non-autolayout views. Remember, all views you create from code have setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES, you have to disable it for autolayout views. Views created from storyboard have setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO